# require() - directory change

Tags: php

I am using Wamp server, i pull the project and in index.php there is

```
require_once ('app_config_new.php')
```

I have a file structure as follows:

- project/index.php
- project/config/app_config_new.php

what should i change in apache config file to work this code

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Apache configuration.

In file `index.php` you must set the path to `app_config_new.php`, like this:

```php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/config/app_config_new.php');
```

Comment: Ok, but you cannot change it over Apache, you must update it directly in PHP.

Comment: @David, this is the way to go, with your project structure it is not possible without code change

Comment: If you don't want to change the code, you can create a shortcut/symlink to the actual file, and place it where your code thinks it is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @David Zadražil is the desired one, but if you can't or don't want to change the code, you can change [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in your `php.ini` to include the directory with `app_config_new.php`:

```
include_path=".;c:\your_path_to_project\config"
```

Restart you Apache (if using mod_php) or PHP-FPM afterwards.